# Proper implementation AES-256 for single block E_k then being used on AES-GCM

Tags: aes, block-cipher, symmetric, aes-gcm

My first objective is to implement AES-GCM in PowerShell 5.1 since there is not an implementation that not use external dll libraries.

According to the GCM schema of encryption:
[image: GCM Encryption]

the E_k block should correspond to a 128-bit block and the input is encrypted by AES with a specific key K.

If at the beginning I want to focus only on the E_k block and I want to implement directly there the AES algorithm, is it correct saying that in that case no Block Cipher mode is applied because I'm focusing only on the block itself?

A further doubt: in the case of GCM, if each E_k takes as input 12 bytes IV +counter_value and each E_k block is sized 16 bytes (128 bits), the IV is padded with 0 (or another predefined value) for the next 4 bytes to reach 16 bytes of size? So for each block we have, for example, [BLOCK 0] 7808B1A23DDC2F9D90A4BCED00000000; [BLOCK 1] 7808B1A23DDC2F9D90A4BCED00000001; [BLOCK 2] 7808B1A23DDC2F9D90A4BCED00000002; and so on?

Could this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81989/aes-ecb-vs-aes-cbc-for-16-bytes) be applied also in my case so:

- the "raw" AES could be applied by using ECB for the single E_k block?
- padding the plaintext (in our case the 12-byte IV) up to 16 bytes with 4 bytes of 0s?

I hope the information is clear.

Thank you

Comment: The question is uncomfortably too close to a programming question, which is off-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). That said: you want the true [spec of AES-GCM](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf#page=23). Yes raw AES corresponds to ECB mode, and can be used to implement the $E_k$ boxes in the question. I think your description of the IV is off-by-one, and the first block ends in 00000001h. But again, read the spec. And I do not condone writing serious crypto in PowerShell.

Comment: @fgrieu Dont' worry for the "programming" part, for me the "theorical" part was important. With this information I can proceed to the programming part on my own.
I just don't understand why my description of the IV is off-by-one. The first block does not end in 00000001h but 00000000h.
I proceed to edit the question and the body to focus more on the "theory" and not "programmin". Thank you anyway

Comment: I say your IV is off-by-one because of the $J_0 = IV\mathbin\|0^{31}\mathbin\|1$ equation (when $IV$ is 96-bit, matching the 12-byte of the question) in the linked spec. At least I'm positive this means $J_0$ ends in 00000001h.

Comment: Sorry, again, in the "first block" for the authentication tag the counter starts from 1. I'm blind. The "Counter 0" confused me. You're right. And I'm also reading that "an IV set to all zero bytes may leak part of the GHASH value". Thank you again.

Comment: `implement AES-GCM in PowerShell 5.1 since.. ` when I see custom implementations, I'm usually concerned about resistance against side channel attacks. if you are really looking for a safer solution, why not to call e. g. OpenSSL command?

Comment: @gusto2 yes, you're right. In my case I want to try less dependant by external dep, but in my particular need, in reality, I need only to decrypt by taking as input Additional Auth Data, IV, Encrypted Dat and Auth Tag, so I'm going to implement just for personal purpose, exclusively the decryption function. But for this purpose I needed to understand better that doubt I explained in the encryption process above.